# Pasar una letra de minúscula a mayúscula en PHP

Tags: php, funciones, ascii

Buenas, tengo un ejercicio en PHP donde la variable `$letra` le asigno la letra 'm', esa variable la paso como parámetro a una función para convertirla en mayúscula a través de su código ASCII

Código:

```
<?php   
    echo "<h2>Letra minuscula a mayuscula</h2>";
    $letra = "m";
    echo "La letra minuscula es: ".$letra."<br>";
    echo "Pasando la letra minuscula a la funcion...<br><br>";
    function minusToMayus($letra)
    {
        $letra = chr(77);
        return $letra;
    }       
    $letra = minusToMayus($letra);
    echo "La letra minuscula se a convertido mayuscula: ".$letra;    
?>
```

No puedo utilizar la función `strtoupper()`, lo que necesito es hacer otra función que me valide que realmente la variable `$letra` es minúscula entonces convertirla en mayúsculas, en caso contrario mostrar un mensaje diciendo que la letra ya esta en mayúsculas.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas en la tabla ASCII, las mayúsculas están siempre 32 enteros por debajo de las minúsculas, esto significa que obteniendo el código ASCII de tu minúscula, en este caso "m" (código ASCII: 109), le restas 32 y obtienes la "M" (código ASCII: 77).

Nota: función ord() te da el valor ASCII de un carácter, por el contrario, la función chr() te da el carácter pasándole un código ASCII.

```
<?php   
echo "<h2>Letra minuscula a mayuscula</h2>";
$letra = "m";
echo "La letra minuscula es: ".$letra."<br>";
echo "Pasando la letra minuscula a la funcion...<br><br>";
function minusToMayus($letra)
{
    $letra = ord($letra);
    //Comprobamos que el codigo ASCII obtenido sea una letra en minuscula
    if ($letra >= 97 && $letra <= 122) {
    $letra = chr($letra - 32);
    echo "La letra minuscula se a convertido mayuscula: ".$letra;
    }
    return $letra;
}       
$letra = minusToMayus($letra);
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me ha servido de mucho tu ayuda, pero hay un error, no es `odd($letra)` es `ord($letra)` me equivoco?

Comment: Tienes razón, editado.

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo otra posibilidad de convertir una letra en mayúscula con la función [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.range.php) y [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php), incluyendo una función la cual comprueba si la letra ya estaba en mayúscula con [`ctype_upper()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ctype-upper.php):

<kbd>[Ver Demo Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd9fc7850a25afa2febf081f64b2a3bcc66cb592)</kbd>

```
<?php

function convertir_a_mayuscula( $letra ) {

    $letras_minusculas = range( 'a', 'z' );
    $letras_mayusculas = range( 'A', 'Z' );

    return str_replace( $letras_minusculas, $letras_mayusculas, $letra );
}

function es_mayuscula( $letra ) {

    return ctype_upper( $letra );
}

function comprobar_letra( $letra ) {

    if ( es_mayuscula( $letra ) ) {

        $resultado = "ya estaba en mayúscula!";
    }
    else {

        $letra_convertido = convertir_a_mayuscula( $letra );
        $resultado        = "se ha convertido a mayúscula: {$letra_convertido}";
    }

    return "La letra {$letra} {$resultado}";
}

echo comprobar_letra( 'm' ); // La letra m se ha convertido a mayúscula: M
echo comprobar_letra( 'M' ); // La letra M ya estaba en mayúscula!
```

---

**BONUS:**

Ahora, si alguien te dijera quiero que convierta también las letras con acentos y no puedas usar [`mb_strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtoupper.php), entonces puedes usar [`mb_convert_case()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-case.php).

Y para comprobar si la letra es mayúscula usamos la expresión regular `/\p{Lu}/u` cual comprueba caracteres [Unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html):

<kbd>[Ver Demo Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/009a4e1d61dc35ffd8c09de59001011aed0f2d92)</kbd>

```
function convertir_a_mayuscula( $letra ) {

    return mb_convert_case($letra, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
}

function es_mayuscula( $letra ) {

    return preg_match("/\p{Lu}/u", $letra);
}

function comprobar_letra( $letra ) {

    if ( es_mayuscula( $letra ) ) {

        $resultado = "ya estaba en mayúscula!";
    }
    else {

        $letra_convertido = convertir_a_mayuscula( $letra );
        $resultado        = "se ha convertido a mayúscula: {$letra_convertido}";
    }

    return "La letra {$letra} {$resultado}";
}

echo comprobar_letra( 'á' ); // La letra á se ha convertido a mayúscula: Á
echo comprobar_letra( 'ü' ); // La letra ü se ha convertido a mayúscula: Ü
echo comprobar_letra( 'x' ); // La letra x se ha convertido a mayúscula: X
echo comprobar_letra( 'Ó' ); // La letra Ó ya estaba en mayúscula!
echo comprobar_letra( 'T' ); // La letra T ya estaba en mayúscula!
```