# Palabra minúscula a mayúscula en PHP sin usar strtoupper()

Tags: php, funciones, ascii

Tengo el siguiente código que convierte una letra minúscula a mayúscula

Codigo:

```
<?php   
    echo "<h2>Letra minuscula a mayuscula</h2>";
    $letra = "m";
    echo "La letra minuscula es: ".$letra."<br>";
    echo "Pasando la letra minuscula a la funcion...<br><br>";

    function minusToMayus($letra)
    {
        $ascii = ord($letra);
        echo "La letra ".$letra." tiene como ascii: ".$ascii."<br>";
        $letra = chr($ascii - 32);
        echo "Le restamos 32 para obtener el codigo ascii de su mayuscula<br><br>";

        return $letra;
    }       
        $letra = minusToMayus($letra);
        echo "La letra minúscula se a convertido mayúscula: ".$letra;       
?>
```

Como seria para en vez de convertir una letra fuese una palabra? 
Tendría que convertir un string a un arreglo?

Comment: Sin usar funciones predefinidas, puedes hacer un `str_split` para dividir tu string en un arreglo, tomar cada elemento del arreglo, pasarlo a mayúsculas y después de eso concatenarlo todo en un nuevo string, pero ¿Por qué no querrías usar al función de PHP que ya hace eso?

Comment: Porque la profesora mando este ejercicio pero que no usáramos funciones predefinidas, porque eso seria lo fácil supongo xDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya lo tienes hecho para una letra. Hacerlo para una frase sería muy simple: tan sólo tienes que hacer un bucle atravesando la cadena y transformando cada letra individualmente.

Por ejemplo, aquí lo tienes con un bucle `for`:

```
<?php   
    echo "<h2>Frase minuscula a mayuscula</h2>";
    $frase = "frase";
    echo "La letra minuscula es: ".$frase."<br>";
    echo "Pasando la letra minuscula a la funcion...<br><br>";

    function minusToMayus($frase)
    {
        for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($frase); $x++) {
            $ascii = ord($frase[$x]);
            echo "La letra ".$frase." tiene como ascii: ".$ascii."<br>";
            $frase[$x] = chr($ascii - 32);
            echo "Le restamos 32 para obtener el codigo ascii de su mayuscula<br><br>";
        }
        return $frase;
    }       

    $frase = minusToMayus($frase);
    echo "La frase minúscula se ha convertido mayúscula: ".$frase;       
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro, tenias razón ya lo tenia hecho, no se como no me di cuenta :)

Comment: cachis... he cambiado 3 veces el código... una porque lo hice con `split` y luego me pareció demasiado y lo cambie ... y luego me di cuenta que haz hecho lo mismo ... xD ... en fin... +1

Answer (score 2):

Usando la función que te he dejado en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/106248/6491) y haciendo algunos cambios, se quedaría de esta manera (explicación en los comentarios):

<kbd>[Ver Demo Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63d408b3cff6bf444ff2d31729a3d1b562aa100a)</kbd>

```
function convertir_a_mayuscula( $letra ) {

    $letras_minusculas = range( 'a', 'z' );
    $letras_mayusculas = range( 'A', 'Z' );

    return str_replace( $letras_minusculas, $letras_mayusculas, $letra );
}

function es_mayuscula( $letra ) {

    return ctype_upper( $letra );
}

function comprobar_letra( $cadena ) {

    if ( es_mayuscula( $cadena ) ) {

        $resultado = "ya estaba en mayúscula!";
    }
    else {

        // Dividimos la cadena en letra
        $string_split = str_split( $cadena );

        // Iniciamos un array
        $arr_string = [];

        // Pasamos todas la letra a convertirlo en mayúscula
        foreach($string_split as $v ) {

            // Guardamos en el array todas las letras en mayúsculas
            $arr_string[] = convertir_a_mayuscula( $v );
        }

        // Unimos todas letras en una cadena
        $cadena_uppercase = join($arr_string);            
        $resultado        = "se ha convertido a mayúscula: {$cadena_uppercase}";
    }

    return "La cadena {$cadena} {$resultado}";
}

echo comprobar_letra( 'madrid' ); // La cadena madrid se ha convertido a mayúscula: MADRID
echo comprobar_letra( 'MALAGA' ); // La cadena MALAGA ya estaba en mayúscula!

echo comprobar_letra( 'BarCEloNa' ); // La cadena BarCEloNa se ha convertido a mayúscula: BARCELONA
```

Comment: ¿Cómo creas la demo online e insertas el icono?

Comment: si pinchas en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/106258/edit)... lo verás ;)